# EmberJS Examples not Working

Tags: ember.js

On the Homepage of EmberJS there are short code snippets:

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
  firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  lastName: DS.attr('string'),

  fullName: function() {
    return this.get('firstName') +
       " " + this.get('lastName');
    }.property('firstName', 'lastName')
});

App.peopleController = Em.ArrayController.create({
    content: App.Person.find()
});
```

Now when I am trying to build this I get an DS is undefined?  I did include Handlebars, and looking thru the sourcecode there is nowhere a defintion to be found for DS.

Other examples on the net dont use DS, but Em, but these Examples are pretty old (in internettime at least).  What am I doing wrong?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

`DS` is ember-data. You need to include it in order to use `DS`: [ember-data on github](https://github.com/emberjs/data).

Ember-data is Ember's persistence library (models and server communication).

Comment: So basically ember as shown on the ember homepage is not functioning unless you compile the not mentioned ember-data module?

Comment: Yes, I suppose the homepage example was not meant as a getting started guide, but more as a preview of how an ember.js app looks like.  
Here are a couple of screencasts to get you started: http://emberwatch.com/#screencasts

Comment: actually i guess their plan is to merge ember-data with emberJS once its get stabilized..currently it has long way to get that...

Comment: Thanks for the link, unfortunately I can choose to pay 12 bucks, or watch horribly outdated videos.  Not helpfull.  Seems like I am going to use something else for now, but thanks again for the help!!!

Comment: This one is free and up to date: http://toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2013/03/02/emberjs-rc1-introduction-screencast/
I wouldn't give up very quickly, Ember.js has been very rewarding.